# NPM failing to install packages outside of global

Tags: node.js, npm, archlinux

I've installed Node.js off of the [pacman](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/nodejs/) package. After that, I globally installed express.js via `npm`.

After creating a new express project, it tells me to run `$ cd . && npm install`.

I've tried as both a regular user and as root, and it has the same result.

### STDOUT:

```
[jarred@development express]$ npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-2.5.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade/-/jade-0.20.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-2.5.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade/-/jade-0.20.3.tgz

npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error 'jade.js'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.7-1-ARCH
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /media/code/express
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.1
npm ERR! path jade.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /media/code/express/node_modules/___jade.npm/package/lib/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_type SymbolicLink
npm ERR! fstream_class LinkWriter
npm ERR! fstream_linkpath jade.js
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! message UNKNOWN, unknown error 'jade.js'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/link-writer.js:77:24)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /media/code/express/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

### Contents of npm-debug.log

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install' ]
info using npm@1.1.1
info using node@v0.6.11
verbose config file /root/.npmrc
verbose config file /usr/etc/npmrc
verbose config file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc
verbose caching /media/code/express/package.json
verbose loadDefaults application-name@0.0.1
verbose where, deps [ '/media/code/express', [ 'express', 'jade' ] ]
verbose from cache /media/code/express/package.json
info preinstall application-name@0.0.1
verbose from cache /media/code/express/package.json
verbose cache add [ 'jade@>= 0.0.1', null ]
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ undefined, 'jade@>= 0.0.1', [ 'jade@>= 0.0.1', null ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: 'jade@', path: 'jade@', href: 'jade@' }
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ 'jade', '>= 0.0.1', [ 'jade', '>= 0.0.1' ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: '=', path: '=', href: '=' }
verbose addNamed [ 'jade', '>= 0.0.1' ]
verbose addNamed [ null, '>=0.0.1' ]
silly name, range, hasData [ 'jade', '>=0.0.1', false ]
verbose raw, before any munging jade
verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './jade' ]
verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
verbose etag "B3Z4JA5MEYM82WN7DP0FFMSYT"
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
verbose cache add [ 'express@2.5.8', null ]
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ undefined, 'express@2.5.8', [ 'express@2.5.8', null ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: 'express@2.5.8',
verbose parsed url   path: 'express@2.5.8',
verbose parsed url   href: 'express@2.5.8' }
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ 'express', '2.5.8', [ 'express', '2.5.8' ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: '2.5.8', path: '2.5.8', href: '2.5.8' }
verbose addNamed [ 'express', '2.5.8' ]
verbose addNamed [ '2.5.8', '2.5.8' ]
verbose raw, before any munging express/2.5.8
verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './express/2.5.8' ]
verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.8
verbose etag "3C8IV1I96MAC8GUQ2925I9XD4"
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.8
http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.8
silly get cb [ 304,
silly get cb   { server: 'CouchDB/1.1.0 (Erlang OTP/R14B04)',
silly get cb     etag: '"3C8IV1I96MAC8GUQ2925I9XD4"',
silly get cb     date: 'Mon, 27 Feb 2012 00:46:10 GMT',
silly get cb     'content-length': '0' } ]
verbose etag express/2.5.8 from cache
verbose bin dist [ '0.6-ares1.7.5-DEV-evundefined-openssl1.0.0g-v83.6.6.20-linux-ia32-3.2.7-1-ARCH',
verbose bin dist   { shasum: 'f166b55d4e8c6d2307ef88ad1768209613f7452a',
verbose bin dist     tarball: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-2.5.8.tgz' } ]
verbose caching /root/.npm/express/2.5.8/package/package.json
verbose loadDefaults express@2.5.8
http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
silly get cb [ 304,
silly get cb   { server: 'CouchDB/1.1.0 (Erlang OTP/R14B04)',
silly get cb     etag: '"B3Z4JA5MEYM82WN7DP0FFMSYT"',
silly get cb     date: 'Mon, 27 Feb 2012 00:46:10 GMT',
silly get cb     'content-length': '0' } ]
verbose etag jade from cache
silly name, range, hasData 2 [ 'jade', '>=0.0.1', true ]
silly versions [ 'jade',
silly versions   [ '0.0.1',
silly versions     '0.0.2',
silly versions     '0.1.0',
silly versions     '0.2.0',
silly versions     '0.2.1',
silly versions     '0.2.2',
silly versions     '0.2.3',
silly versions     '0.2.4',
silly versions     '0.3.0',
silly versions     '0.4.0',
silly versions     '0.4.1',
silly versions     '0.5.0',
silly versions     '0.5.1',
silly versions     '0.5.2',
silly versions     '0.5.3',
silly versions     '0.5.4',
silly versions     '0.5.5',
silly versions     '0.5.6',
silly versions     '0.5.7',
silly versions     '0.6.0',
silly versions     '0.6.1',
silly versions     '0.6.3',
silly versions     '0.7.0',
silly versions     '0.7.1',
silly versions     '0.8.0',
silly versions     '0.8.1',
silly versions     '0.8.2',
silly versions     '0.8.3',
silly versions     '0.8.4',
silly versions     '0.8.5',
silly versions     '0.8.6',
silly versions     '0.8.7',
silly versions     '0.8.8',
silly versions     '0.8.9',
silly versions     '0.9.0',
silly versions     '0.9.1',
silly versions     '0.9.2',
silly versions     '0.9.3',
silly versions     '0.10.0',
silly versions     '0.10.1',
silly versions     '0.10.2',
silly versions     '0.10.3',
silly versions     '0.10.4',
silly versions     '0.10.5',
silly versions     '0.10.6',
silly versions     '0.10.7',
silly versions     '0.11.0',
silly versions     '0.11.1',
silly versions     '0.12.0',
silly versions     '0.12.1',
silly versions     '0.12.2',
silly versions     '0.12.3',
silly versions     '0.12.4',
silly versions     '0.13.0',
silly versions     '0.14.0',
silly versions     '0.14.1',
silly versions     '0.14.2',
silly versions     '0.15.0',
silly versions     '0.15.1',
silly versions     '0.15.2',
silly versions     '0.15.3',
silly versions     '0.15.4',
silly versions     '0.16.0',
silly versions     '0.16.1',
silly versions     '0.16.2',
silly versions     '0.16.3',
silly versions     '0.16.4',
silly versions     '0.17.0',
silly versions     '0.18.0',
silly versions     '0.19.0',
silly versions     '0.20.0',
silly versions     '0.20.1',
silly versions     '0.20.2',
silly versions     '0.20.3' ] ]
verbose bin dist [ '0.6-ares1.7.5-DEV-evundefined-openssl1.0.0g-v83.6.6.20-linux-ia32-3.2.7-1-ARCH',
verbose bin dist   { shasum: '7f43cbc7103762abb72a67fd6484eb72ac1d28a0',
verbose bin dist     tarball: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/jade/-/jade-0.20.3.tgz' } ]
verbose caching /root/.npm/jade/0.20.3/package/package.json
verbose loadDefaults jade@0.20.3
silly resolved [ { name: 'express',
silly resolved     description: 'Sinatra inspired web development framework',
silly resolved     version: '2.5.8',
silly resolved     author: { name: 'TJ Holowaychuk', email: 'tj@vision-media.ca' },
silly resolved     contributors: 
silly resolved      [ { name: 'TJ Holowaychuk', email: 'tj@vision-media.ca' },
silly resolved        { name: 'Aaron Heckmann',
silly resolved          email: 'aaron.heckmann+github@gmail.com' },
silly resolved        { name: 'Ciaran Jessup', email: 'ciaranj@gmail.com' },
silly resolved        { name: 'Guillermo Rauch', email: 'rauchg@gmail.com' } ],
silly resolved     dependencies: { connect: '1.x', mime: '1.2.4', qs: '0.4.x', mkdirp: '0.3.0' },
silly resolved     devDependencies: 
silly resolved      { 'connect-form': '0.2.1',
silly resolved        ejs: '0.4.2',
silly resolved        expresso: '0.9.2',
silly resolved        hamljs: '0.6.x',
silly resolved        jade: '0.16.2',
silly resolved        stylus: '0.13.0',
silly resolved        should: '0.3.2',
silly resolved        'express-messages': '0.0.2',
silly resolved        'node-markdown': '>= 0.0.1',
silly resolved        'connect-redis': '>= 0.0.1' },
silly resolved     keywords: [ 'framework', 'sinatra', 'web', 'rest', 'restful' ],
silly resolved     repository: { type: 'git', url: 'git://github.com/visionmedia/express.git' },
silly resolved     main: 'index',
silly resolved     bin: { express: './bin/express' },
silly resolved     scripts: { test: 'make test', prepublish: 'npm prune' },
silly resolved     engines: { node: '>= 0.4.1 < 0.7.0' },
silly resolved     _id: 'express@2.5.8',
silly resolved     optionalDependencies: {},
silly resolved     _engineSupported: true,
silly resolved     _npmVersion: '1.1.1',
silly resolved     _nodeVersion: 'v0.6.11',
silly resolved     _defaultsLoaded: true },
silly resolved   { name: 'jade',
silly resolved     description: 'Jade template engine',
silly resolved     version: '0.20.3',
silly resolved     author: { name: 'TJ Holowaychuk', email: 'tj@vision-media.ca' },
silly resolved     repository: { type: 'git', url: 'git://github.com/visionmedia/jade.git' },
silly resolved     main: './index.js',
silly resolved     bin: { jade: './bin/jade' },
silly resolved     dependencies: { commander: '0.5.x', mkdirp: '>= 0.0.7' },
silly resolved     devDependencies: 
silly resolved      { mocha: '*',
silly resolved        'coffee-script': '>= 0.0.1',
silly resolved        markdown: '>= 0.0.1',
silly resolved        stylus: '>= 0.0.1',
silly resolved        uubench: '0.0.1',
silly resolved        'uglify-js': '>= 1.0.7' },
silly resolved     scripts: { prepublish: 'npm prune' },
silly resolved     engines: { node: '>= 0.1.98' },
silly resolved     _id: 'jade@0.20.3',
silly resolved     optionalDependencies: {},
silly resolved     _engineSupported: true,
silly resolved     _npmVersion: '1.1.1',
silly resolved     _nodeVersion: 'v0.6.11',
silly resolved     _defaultsLoaded: true } ]
info into /media/code/express express@2.5.8
info into /media/code/express jade@0.20.3
info installOne express@2.5.8
info installOne jade@0.20.3
info unbuild /media/code/express/node_modules/express
info unbuild /media/code/express/node_modules/jade
verbose from cache /root/.npm/express/2.5.8/package/package.json
verbose from cache /root/.npm/jade/0.20.3/package/package.json
verbose unpack_ uid, gid [ 0, 0 ]
verbose unpackTarget /media/code/express/node_modules/express
silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
verbose unpack_ uid, gid [ 0, 0 ]
verbose unpackTarget /media/code/express/node_modules/jade
silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error 'jade.js'
ERR! You may report this log at:
ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
ERR! or email it to:
ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
ERR! 
ERR! System Linux 3.2.7-1-ARCH
ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
ERR! cwd /media/code/express
ERR! node -v v0.6.11
ERR! npm -v 1.1.1
ERR! path jade.js
ERR! fstream_path /media/code/express/node_modules/___jade.npm/package/lib/index.js
ERR! fstream_type SymbolicLink
ERR! fstream_class LinkWriter
ERR! fstream_linkpath jade.js
ERR! code UNKNOWN
ERR! message UNKNOWN, unknown error 'jade.js'
ERR! errno {}
ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/link-writer.js:77:24)
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

### What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue specific to Arch Linux i686. I installed Ubuntu Server and it worked out of the box.